# Should this bit of C++ CRTP code compile, and if so what should it do?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading, crtp

I was thinking about using CRTP classes to help with overloading and wondered what the following bit of code would do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class TDerived>
class FunctionImplementation
{
};

class AbstractFunction
{
};

class BaseFunction : public AbstractFunction, public FunctionImplementation<BaseFunction>
{
};

class DerivedFunction : public BaseFunction, public FunctionImplementation<DerivedFunction>
{
};

template <class TDerived>
void foo(const FunctionImplementation<TDerived>& function) {
    std::cout << "In foo for " << typeid(TDerived).name() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    BaseFunction base;
    DerivedFunction derived;

    foo(base);
    foo(derived);
}
```

With GCC 4.2 on OS X it doesn't compile:

```
overload.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
overload.cpp:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(DerivedFunction&)’
```

With Clang 4.0 on the same system, it compiles and does the 'natural' thing when it runs:

```
In foo for 12BaseFunction
In foo for 15DerivedFunction
```

With Visual C++ 2010, it also compiles but runs differently:

```
In foo for class BaseFunction
In foo for class BaseFunction
```

Finally, GCC 4.7.2 on Linux does not compile but gives a more complete and fairly authoritative-sounding error message:

```
overload.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
overload.cpp:31:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(DerivedFunction&)’
overload.cpp:31:16: note: candidate is:
overload.cpp:22:6: note: template<class TDerived> void foo(const FunctionImplementation<TDerived>&)
overload.cpp:22:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
overload.cpp:31:16: note:   ‘DerivedFunction’ is an ambiguous base class of ‘const FunctionImplementation<TDerived>’
```

Which is correct? I am no expert at navigating the language standard...

Comment: Using a class as a base class for the class seems dubious.

Comment: Did you mean to derive DerivedFunction from BaseFunction because that means DerivedFunction has two FunctionImplementation<> base classes?

Comment: This is not actual code...I was thinking about having a class hierarchy with an abstract base class (AbstractFunction) and then having each leaf class CRTP-inherit from FunctionImplementation<TDerived> so I could have a function (actually a constructor, in my case) that would accept 'all leaf subclasses of AbstractFunction'. Then I wondered what would happen if someone (perhaps myself!) accidentally misused the code by subclassing from one of those leaf classes and inheriting the new leaf class from FunctionImplementation<TDerived> again, so I decided to experiment to see what would happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I believe gcc is right. You are asking the compiler to perform type deduction for you, and the problem is that the given argument of type `DerivedFunction` is not a `FunctionImplementation<TDerived>` directly, so a conversion has to be performed. At this point the list of conversions includes `FunctionImplementation<BaseFunction>` (through `BaseFunction`) and `FunctionImplementation<DerivedFunction>` (directly). There is no ordering among those two choices, so the compiler bails out with an ambiguity.

The standard treats this in §14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call]/4,5

> (paragraph 4) In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow a difference:
>
> [...]
>
> If P is a class and P has the form simple-template-id, then the transformed A can be a derived class of the deduced A. Likewise, if P is a pointer to a class of the form simple-template-id, the transformed A can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced A.
>
> (paragraph 5) These alternatives are considered only if type deduction would otherwise fail. If they yield more than one possible deduced A, the type deduction fails.

In the 4th paragraph it allows type deduction to pick a base of the argument type, in this case there are 2 such bases. The 5th paragraph determines that if the application of the previous rule yields more than one result, then type deduction fails.

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for. I wish Clang and Visual Studio implemented this properly so I could rely on the compiler catching the error as a way of ensuring the class hierarchy was set up properly.

Comment: @IanMackenzie: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Would you rather have only the most derived instance? (That is easy, i.e. having a behavior that is consistent across compilers, by adding a dispatcher template that takes `T` and calls `foo<FunctionImplementation<T>>`) or would you rather not have this compile at all? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? There might be simpler approaches than this...

Comment: @dribeas: I have a `Function` class which contains a pointer to an `AbstractFunction` (pimpl idiom), and can be constructed from such a pointer (`Function function = new ConcreteFunction(...)`). I was trying to find a way to allow things like `Function function = ConcreteFunction(...)` while preserving overloading. (For instance, having functions like `operator+(Function, Function)` would really mess things up if `Function` had a constructor from arbitrary `T`). I could probably do something with `enable_if` and/or C++11 `final` classes, but ultimately decided the whole idea was a bad one.

Comment: @IanMackenzie: Not sure I fully understand what you want, but you might consider using type erasure in the same way that `std::function` does. Have `Function` take a `ConcreteFunction` by const-reference, and internally wrap that in a dynamically allocated (`new`-ed) object that is stored inside the `Function` object.

Comment: @dribeas: That's exactly what I was planning to do, but I was looking for a clean way to do it for many different types of concrete function (`SumFunction`, `ProductFunction` etc.) without having to have a different `Function` constructor overload for each one.

Comment: @IanMackenzie: Same recommendation... so as `std::function` does... provide a templated constructor that matches everything, and inside the template figure out what you really need. There is no need for the type hierarchy (on the interface, you will need it in the implementation) or the CRTP

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24836/discussion-between-ian-mackenzie-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer below is wrong.  I had always believed from reading 13.3.1p7

> In each case where a candidate is a function template, candidate function template specializations are generated using template argument deduction (14.8.3, 14.8.2). Those candidates are then handled as candidate functions in the usual way.

that template argument deduction used the appropriate overload resolution machinery to choose among the syntactically-possible specializations (function overload resolution for functions, etc.).

It turns out that's not true: template argument deduction has its own, very restricted set of rules that insist on exact matches (pace cv-qualifiers and dereferencing and the like), only permitting the derived-class-to-templated-base argument conversion seen here as a special case -- and that special case explicitly forbids using function overload resolution to handle any ambiguities.

So for the right answer, see above.  I'm leaving this answer here because it's getting upvotes, leading me to believe I'm not the only one who has it wrong this way:

Overload resolution for `foo(derived)` is looking up `FunctionImplementation<T>` declarations in class `Derived`.  Class `Derived` has no member-scope declarations of that template, so the recursive lookup results from its base classes are combined, yielding both of the specializations in its hierarchy:

```
Derived
:   Base
    :   AbstractFunction
    ,   FunctionImplementation<Base>
,   FunctionImplementation<Derived>
```

Considering the depth at which a declaration was found within the base-class derivation hierarchy when doing name lookup would mean no name or base could ever be added to a class without *silently* affecting previous results in all derived classes that use multiple inheritance.  Instead, C++ refuses to pick for you and supplies using-declarations to explicitly declare which base class's use of the (tepmlate, in this case) name is the one you mean to refer to.

The standardese for this is in 10.2, p3-5 are the meat.

Comment: My only doubt is whether the bases would be flattened (as I and you seem to believe) or else lookup would be done following the 10.2 section. If it follows the 10.2 section, as per paragraph 5 then VS and clang are correct as the lookup set is extended only with the direct bases. On the other hand, my feeling is that when conversions are involved, lookup does **not** follow the 10.2 section at all. Consider `struct A {}; struct B:A {}; struct C:A,B {}; void f(A);` a call to `f` with an instance of `C` is ambiguous as there are two derived-to-base conversions available...

Comment: @dribeas: I assume you mean that VS and Clang would both be correct only in that they both accept the code - I don't see how the actual behaviour of the VS-compiled code (using an indirect base class even when a direct one is available) could possibly be correct. That was the only one that to me looked _obviously_ wrong =)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I don't see how you get that from 10.2 - see 10.2p5, it's an explicit union of all bases's declarations

Comment: @jthill: 10.2p5 *Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the resulting declaration set is empty), S(f,C) is initially empty. If C has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f **in each direct base class** subobject Bi, and merge each such lookup set S(f,Bi) in turn into S(f,C).* -- Lookup does not merge the results of all the bases at once, it moves up one level at a time until the first element is found, and then stops (the reason for function *hiding*, and probably the reason VS/clang do that)

Comment: @IanMackenzie: I missed the output from VS... that is non-sense. My interpretation is that gcc is correct, as regular lookup is not what the standard dictates for conversions (you can test that in all compilers with the code in the first comment here). The implementation in clang is probably following usual lookup rules and stopping after finding the first match (wrong in my opinion), VS is just bollocks.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It says to merge the lookup sets for each direct base in turn.  How do you read that to not merge the lookup set for some of the direct bases?

Comment: @jthill: There is some kind of misunderstanding, what I tried to say is the opposite: 10.2p5 determines the order of lookup, it will *start* with the current type, then if the lookup set is empty, it will move to the **direct** bases, if the lookup set is still empty it will move one step further up in the inheritance chain. But if the lookup set is non-empty at any level, it won't continue moving up. If that same approach was used for function template argument deduction, lookup would find `FunctionImplementation<DerivedFunction>` and not ` FunctionImplementation<BaseFunction>`

Comment: 10.2p6 specifies the result of each merge step. nowhere I can see does the standard say to skip steps. Step "0": declaration sets's empty, so merge base-class sets.  Step 1: I presume we agree the `Base` lookup set contains `FunctionImplementation<Base>`  by recursion, and the result of the merge at this step is that declaration. Step 2: `<FunctionImplementation<Derived>` lookup set contains itself by injection.  Neither of the first two conditions in 10.2p6 apply so the result is the union. How do you justify skipping step two here?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas See my comment above and the edit I made to my answer, I see now that I should have been more specific about what shouldn't be considered.

Comment: @jthill: I am not sure I understand the answer then. You are suggesting that the correct implementation is that of clang and that in the case of `Derived` it should call `foo<Derived>`? That is what 10.2p3-5 state (in particular p5), or are you saying that all bases should be considered (which is what you depict in the drawing in the answer)? 10.2p5 contradicts the drawing in your answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24847/discussion-between-jthill-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)