# How alternative deductions can yield more than one possible "deduced A"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Per [[temp.deduct.call]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-5)

> These alternatives ([[temp.deduct.call]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-4)) are considered only
> if type deduction would otherwise fail. **If they yield more than one
> possible deduced A, the type deduction fails**. [ Note: If a
> template-parameter is not used in any of the function parameters of a
> function template, or is used only in a non-deduced context, its
> corresponding template-argument cannot be deduced from a function call
> and the template-argument must be explicitly specified. — end note ]

**My question:**

- How these alternative deductions can yield more than one possible "deduced A"?

Please, support the answer with an example that triggers this case.

Comment: It means like `template<typename T> void f(T a, T b){}` and then you call  it like: `f(3, 5.5);`. So this would fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should this bit of C++ CRTP code compile, and if so what should it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971536/should-this-bit-of-c-crtp-code-compile-and-if-so-what-should-it-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
template<typename>
struct B {};

struct D : B<int>, B<double> {};

template<typename T>
void f(B<T>);

int main()
{
    f(D{});
}
```

[[temp.deduct.call]/(4.3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#4.3):

> If `P` is a class and `P` has the form *simple-template-id*, then the transformed `A` can be a derived class `D` of the deduced `A`.

applies here, and 2 deduced `A`s are possible: `B<int>` or `B<double>`. So the type deduction fails.

---

Bonus example: interaction with overload resolution:

```cpp
template<typename>
struct A {};
template<typename>
struct B {};

struct D1 : A<int>, B<int> {};
struct D2 : A<int>, B<int>, B<double> {};

template<typename T>
void f(A<T>); // 1
template<typename T>
void f(B<T>); // 2

int main()
{
    f(D1{}); // error, ambiguous between 1 and 2
    f(D2{}); // calls specialization of 1, because deduction for 2 fails
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> **How these alternative deductions can yield more than one possible "deduced A"?** Please, support the answer with an example that triggers this case.

An example of this can be:

```
template<typename T> 
void f(T a, T b)
{
    
}
int main()
{
    f(3, 5.5); //deduced A as int from first deduction while double from second deduction
    return 0;
}
```

Here we have more than one possible "deduced `A`". From the first argument we've `int` and from the second argument `b` we have `double`.

Comment: @John I agree. Though the question is interesting but is indeed trivial(as you also said) You're welcome :)

Comment: @John In that example where you have `template <class T> void f(T&);int main(void{const int ci{}; f(ci);`, the deduced `A` and the transformed `A` are both `const int` and the deduction isn't failed.

Comment: How is this an example for deducing different A due to difference in constness (or smth. else from https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#4)?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - What other example do you see applicable to this case?

Comment: So, you can't explain how it is related? Where and how the alternatives listed in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#4 are even considered in the example in your answer (if you haven't noticed, the paragraph starts with «These alternatives are considered only if type deduction would otherwise fail»)?